# jfilechooser, how to write a name of the file to textfile

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jfilechooser

I would really appreciate your help in solving this problem.
in my project i have a task to do. Here are the steps involved:

1. Select an image file from disk using jfilechooser and attach image to label in the form. (straight forward)
2. i need to create a text file with the file name using isbn string from one of the textfields in that form. (im creating an instance of the book, have isbn, title, au_name etc)
3. inside this text document, I need to write a path and a file name of that image. For example h:\workplace\isbn1234.txt

That should happen in one method.

Next step would be creating another method, which will use created txt file (found by isbn string) and load image to all related forms. (but im not there yet)

here what ive done so far, but its a mess...

```
private void addPhotoButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 

 {
        final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File("H:\\java"));
            if (evt.getSource() == addPhotoButton) {            
                int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(this);
                if ( returnVal== JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {                 
                 java.io.File file = fc.getSelectedFile( );
                 String s = file.toString( );
                 String file_name = file.getName();
                 photoLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(file_name));
                 try(Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileInputStream (file_name)); 
                         PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("files/" + isbnTxtField.getText() + ".txt" ))){
                 String line = "";
                 while (input.hasNext()) {
                     line = input.nextLine();
                     outputStream.println(line);
                     input.next();
                     }
                    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                        System.out.println("problem opening files.");
                        System.exit(0);}}}}
```

here is the code i came up with to solve 1-3 steps:

```
private void addPhotoButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
 {
        final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File("H:\\java"));
            if (evt.getSource() == addPhotoButton) {            
                int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(this);

                if ( returnVal== JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {                 
                 java.io.File file = fc.getSelectedFile( );
                 try{
                     // Load image to label
                     img = ImageIO.read(file);
                     ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(img);
                     photoLabel.setIcon(icon);
                     Dimension imageSize = new Dimension(icon.getIconWidth(),icon.getIconHeight());
                     photoLabel.setPreferredSize(imageSize);
                     photoLabel.revalidate();
                     photoLabel.repaint();
                     // create textfile with textfield name
                    String file_in =fc.getSelectedFile().getParent();
                        System.out.println(file_in);
                        String fileName =(file_in+ "\\" +isbnTxtField.getText() + ".txt");
                        System.out.println(fileName);
                        File textFile = new File(fileName);

                         if (!textFile.exists()) {
                             textFile.createNewFile();
                            }

                        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(textFile.getAbsoluteFile()); 
                        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                         bw.write(fileName);
                         bw.close();

                    }catch (IOException e){
                        System.out.println("problem opening files.");
                        System.exit(0);}}}}
```

Comment: So what you have done until this step and what is your exact question? I don't see any research or work in your post. You must explain your issue in more detail like which step you got stuck.

Comment: One moment im trying to fit it in here

Comment: You can edit your question, just a tip.

Comment: yeah, i just did. i cant figure out step 2 and 3

Comment: I am confused, you said you want a path in output txt so why are you trying to write image content to output file? What will you expect in your .txt file exactly?

Comment: well spotted. Need to get rid of it then! I need to write a path+ filename made of captured isbn string in textfield to the file to use it later on for loading images to other labels in other frames

Answer (score 0):

For creating the text file, you can use a combination of `FileWriter` and `BufferedWriter`, like so:

```
package com.mkyong;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WriteToFileExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            String content = "This is the content to write into file";

            File file = new File("/users/mkyong/filename.txt");

            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(content);
            bw.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

taken from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/).

If you have a `JTextField` called `foo`, then you can get its text using `foo.getText()`.

You can get the absolute path using `fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()`, you can get the name of the file using `fc.getSelectedFile().getName()`

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much sir! Im starting on it now! Apreciate it!

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to accept the answer if it answers the question and add any comments if you feel this answer is not helpful enough.

Comment: I have another question. How can i get a path to a file in a string whithought a file name it self? i went quite far already, code does almost everything i need in steps 2 and 3 apart that bit. Its not giving a file name the way i want. Absolute path provides a pathi with the name like this: H:\Java\workspace\LMS\files\book.jpg

Comment: got it, its a .getParent();

Comment: You can get a substring from index 0 until the lastIndexOf("\\"), see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29